# App made with Python setuptools installs but won't launch from Desktop shortcut

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, conda

I have a GUI app that another developer wrote that I am trying to turn into a conda package that will install a desktop icon on the desktop that users can then launch seamlessly.

Below is the folder structure and the code that I can share:

```
Documents/
└── project/
    ├── bld.bat
    ├── meta.yaml
    ├── setup.py
    ├── setup.cfg
    └── mygui/
        ├── MainGUI.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __main__.py
        └── images/
            └── icon.ico
```

Documents\project\bld.bat:

```
python setup.py install install_shortcuts
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

Documents\project\meta.yaml:

```
package:
  name: mygui
  version: 1.2.3

source:
  path: ./

build:
  number: 1
  string: py{{ CONDA_PY }}_{{ ARCH }}

requirements:
  build:
    - python 2.7.13
    - pyvisa 1.4
    - setuptools
    - setuptools-shortcut
    - pydaqmx
    - pmw
    - matplotlib
    - pyserial
    - pil

  run:
    - python 2.7.13
    - pyvisa 1.4
    - pydaqmx
    - pmw
    - matplotlib
    - pyserial
    - pil

about:
  license: 
  summary: My GUI application
```

Documents\project\setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mygui',
    version='1.2.3',
    author='Me',
    author_email='me@myemail.com',
    description=(
        "An App I wrote."
    ),
    long_description="Actually, someone else wrote it but I'm making the conda package.",
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'mygui': ['images/*ico'],

    },
    entry_points={
        'gui_scripts': [
            'MyApp = mygui.__main__:main'
        ],
    },
    install_requires=['pyvisa==1.4', 'pmw', 'pydaqmx', 'matplotlib', 'pyserial', 'pil']
)
```

Documents\project\setup.cfg:

```
[install]
single-version-externally-managed=1
record=out.txt

[install_shortcuts]
iconfile=mygui/images/icon.ico
name=MyApp
group=My Custom Apps
desktop=1
```

Documents\project\mygui__main__.py:

```
from MainGUI import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The original GUI developer had a code block in a block that went like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   <code here>
```

so I took all the code where  would be and put it cut/paste it into:

```
def main():
    <code here>

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

all inside the MainGUI.py file. I cannot share the specifics of the code. But it works as I'll describe below.

When I open up my code in PyCharm and hit run or debug in a conda environment with all the packages listed in the meta.yaml file the application works just fine with no warnings or errors. However, when I run `conda build`, upload to the anaconda channel, and then install on the machine, the desktop icon gets created but the application won't run when I click on it.

Is there something wrong in my setup files? How can I debug the reason why the application fails? I don't see any command window or output of any kind and PyCharm doesn't complain so it must be something after the application gets made.

**Update:** This is my first time creating a conda package that installs itself as an app like this and I used a colleague's setup.py files as a template. I was curious if the conda package that he created on one of his projects was structurally different from the conda package coming out of my conda-build and it is. If I take that tar.bz file and unzip it this is the structure that I get:

```
mygui-1.2.3-py27_32/
├── info/
    ├── about.json
    ├── files
    ├── has_prefix
    ├── index.json
    └── paths.json
├── Lib/
    └── site-packages
        └── mygui-1.2.3-py2.7.egg-info
            ├── dependency_links.txt
            ├── entry_points.txt
            ├── PKG-INFO
            ├── requires.txt
            ├── SOURCES.txt
            └── top_level.txt
├── Menu/
    ├── mygui.ico
    └── mygui_menu.json
└── Scripts/
    ├── MyApp.exe
    ├── MyApp.manifest
    └── MyApp.pyw
```

But my colleague gets the same structure but he also gets a directory called `Lib/site-packages/mygui/`, for example, which contains the source code in .py and .pyc files and directories. Why is my package not getting these source files and could this be the reason my application won't launch? I also don't see any of my data files which I've indicated in my setup.py file (the *.ico files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get this app made where it would install the shortcuts on the desktop and include the source code.

The problem was with the imports. Since the original source code was written YEARS ago they didn't have absolute_imports.

I had to go through and make sure

```
from __future__ import (
    unicode_literals,
    print_function,
    division,
    absolute_import
)
```

was at the top of every file that made imports and then also change the relative imports to absolute imports. In the root `__init__.py` file, however, I left relative imports. Oh, also another thing I was doing wrong was that in one version of my `setup.py` I was including these four imports. Don't do that or python will complain about the unicode_literals. I just left it out of setup.py and it was fine.

To debug the conda package and find more import errors I would do the following:

1. Test the code in PyCharm by running `__main__.py`.
2. If that worked, I would build the conda package.
3. Install the conda package.
4. In a command window I would run `python "C:\Miniconda2\envs\myenv\Scripts\MyApp-script.pyw"`. This would give me the next error that PyCharm did not.

I would return to the source code, make the necessary change and repeat steps 1-4 until the program launched from the desktop icon.